# Website shows data from Android App - Like WhatsApp Web

Tags: android, web, whatsapp

Does anyone know how **WhatsApp Web** have done this?
They show the messages/data **from the Android phone** connected to the Internet.

So it seems there is **no database** on the server site. They get all messages directly from the mobile app and sends also the changes directly.

How can this be done?
With Firebase or any other Library?

Comment: "So it seems there is no database on the server site. They get all messages directly from the mobile app and sends also the changes directly" -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly? If WhatsApp can access the data, WhatsApp can copy the data to its server-hosted database.

Comment: No proof. That's why I wrote "seems" ;-)

Comment: I need to implement something like this! Did you have some code or ideas to share?

Comment: @sgm: I have made a website now with Firebase Messaging (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging). I sent the added infos from the website to the Android app via Firebase Messaging.

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp created an API which is used both for mobile and web end to communicate to each other and to the main database where all the messages and user information are stored. 
The fact that your phone needs to be turned on and have internet connection still doesn't really show that the website pulls the information out of the phone itself. 
What it is happening, more likely, is that the web extension communicates with the mobile phone linked to it to make sure that the account is still active on the mobile device and then proceeds to pull messages and information out of the database using the API. 
I'm not excluding that the web extension retrieves some information form the device but it probably constantly keeps in sync with it to make sure the account is still active and there is no ambiguity between the account on the web extension and the account currently logged in to the mobile device.
Hope this clarifies a bit but there's no public documentation that I could find online so I'm going by what I believe is the most likely scenario.
:)
P.S. You can have a look here if you haven't already tried:
[WhatApp website FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/?lang=en_US)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I found only user information in WhatsApp FAQ, no detail about how to implement such API.

Comment: I don't think the WhatApp FAQ would go in such details to explain how to build an API. If you are not familiar with the definition of an API I recommend starting with getting some knowledge on restful APIs before continuing with the development of whatever software you are implementing.